# Redirecting rule with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect this type of pages

```
http://domain.com/datas.php?x=a5cc31v211d1s2...
```

to

```
http://domain.com/a5cc31v211d1s2...
```

Note that my `a5cc31v211d1s2...`, is a `md5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ datas.php?x=$1 [L,QSA]
```